# Structure of sentence and position of verb in the end. How to train?

Tags: verb, learning

Now, I learn Deutsch intensive last 8 month. I have a problem with the right structure of sentence. I know that is very important. It's very difficult to place the verb in the end of the sentence. I always forget to place the verb in the end. I think its the influence of my mother language.

For me it is easy to learn grammar, but I always forget to place verb in the end. My teacher always corrects me, but it is not helping. I will be happy to get any advice that could help me.

Here is an example:

> Während Tom U-Bahn gefahren ist, hat er Musik gehört.

I always forget put in the end *habe* or *sein*.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast if there any easy way to train it? In answer below i found good suggestion to write common sentences in Deutsch.

Comment: @IvanR Your SO profile shows that you can easily embed `{ ... }` code blocks into eachother. German is the same. That makes it both wonderful and hard.

Comment: @IvanR What is your first language, Russian? As far I know, the word ordering is not so strict in the slavic languages, so you could easily learn to use it. "Я могу немецкий язык выучить".

Comment: @peterh You are right, my first languages is Russian and Ukrainian. its one problem. Second that i learned other languages(English, Italian, French). Programming is a hobby.

Comment: Welcome to German SE! Could you give an example to show us exactly in what type of construction you often forget to put the verb in the end?

Comment: It is not true that the verb is always placed at the end. Learn about the verb-second rule and the sentence bracket.

Comment: @Philipp example: Wärend Tom U-Bahn gefaren ist, hat er Musik gëhort. I always forget put in the end habe or sein

Comment: I guess there are only two ways to learn it: Read a lot and hear a lot of German language.

Answer (score 3):

> Wä**h**rend Tom U-Bahn gefa**h**ren ist, hat er Musik <s>gëhort</s> gehört.

*I always forget put in the end haben or sein.*

- **It seems your problem is about telling apart main clauses and dependent clauses.**

Let's analyze your example:

> Während Tom U-Bahn gefahren **ist**, …

That's a dependent clause. How do you tell? You can tell it from the *ist* on the last position. It's a conjugated verb, it's on last position → this is a dependent clause.

> …, **hat** er Musik gehört.

That's a declarative main clause. How do you tell? You can tell it from the *hat* on the second position. It's a conjugated verb, it's on second position → this is a declarative  main clause.

Wait, second position? Did you mean *first*? No, **second**. Because from the viewpoint of the main clause, the whole dependent clause is on first position.

Let's analyze an example in *Präsens*:

> Während Tom U-Bahn **fährt**, …
>
> …, **hört** er Musik.

Same pattern.

---

I recommend doing examples in *Präsens Aktiv* or *Präteritum Aktiv*. Because these two don't use participles and auxiliaries but simple forms. Putting only one item at the correct place is simpler than handling two items which may be both as far apart as possible or cheek-by-cheek.

As soon you get a feeling for the placement of the conjugated verb, the tenses and voices with auxiliaries will be no problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not only your problem. Even professional native speakers, for example, politicians, tend to forget the verbs at the end, although they are using much more complex sentences.

My experience is that this mistake makes native speakers need to think some seconds, what you tried to say. Thus, it is an ugly mistake for them, although your sentence remains so or so comprehensible.

Also note, that language teachers are very good to understand everything what you try to say on German, due to their big experience to communicate with low-level speakers. Futhermore, they are using Hochdeutsch. But the common people is not. My experience is that from about two major mistakes becomes your sentence incomprehensible for them, this verb positioning is one. And an incomprehensible sentence means the break of your communication context, and this we never want.

This is a very essential construct in German. You have no other way, you need more practice. If it really won't work in the spoken language, then do this first in writing. There are various translation trainings around, the simplest is: you have a list of sentences on your first language (or on English), and you translate all of them to German. Then your teacher checks the result.

You need to also learn to embed multiple such structures, for example a modalverb in a subordinate clause or in Ausklammerung (*"..., die Sachen erledigen zu können."*). The important thing is the automatization.

My (non-professional, not native speaker) impression is that your language course is focusing probably too strongly to the spoken communcation. *You need clearly more experience in the written language, this is how you can practice the very alien grammatical structures. At first, construct the German sentence as if you would write a program (if you are a programmer), and do this verbally only after you are good in the writing.*

Answer (score 1):

Сконцентрируйтесь! :-)  Я дам вам два предложения.

> Nein, ich **möchte** jetzt nicht **spazieren gehen**.
>
> Ich **möchte** dieses Buch heute noch zu Ende **lesen**.

Write down these sentences, draw rectangular boxes around the verbs in each sentence, and connect these boxes with a line like a very flat u, something like that: l______________I  Now you see the *Verbklammer* / verb clamp / глагольный зажим (?).

Make photocopies and stick them everywhere: on all doors, the mirror, wherever you see them over and over again. That's a kind of промывание мозгов, I know - but it will work. :-))